# Lambda interface name standards Java

Tags: java, lambda, interface, java-8

With the release of Java 8. Lambda became a thing. I was already familiar with the syntax with JavaScript. However something that really anoys me is picking the right names for the user interfaces since in Java you are required to create an interface for every different input a function could have. An example:

```
public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Start().run();

    }

    private void run() {
        Lambda test = () -> {
            System.out.println("Test");
        };
        LambdaNumbers number = (int a, int b) -> a + b;
        test.foo();
        System.out.println(number.foo(5,5));
    }

}

interface Lambda {
    void foo();
}
interface LambdaNumbers {
    int foo(int a, int b);
}
```

Some of the more complex function could have their own unique name. However, you can guess that a simply function that returns void should have a name that makes sence for reproduction. I'm currently using this system for the names of the interfaces:

- **Function:** Return Void
- **Var:** Return String
- **Val:** Return Double
- **Rog:** Return Boolean
- **Dec:** Return Int

Example:

```
interface Function {
    void foo();
}
interface Var {
    String foo();
}
interface Val {
    double foo();
}
interface DecIntInt {
    int foo(int a, int b);
}
```

This is just my way of naming the interfaces. So I was wondering if their is an unwritten rule how to name these things around Java programmers?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to invent your own interfaces. Use the generic ones from [java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html):

1. `Function` → `Runnable`
2. `Var` → `Supplier<String>`
3. `Val` → one of:

   - `DoubleSupplier`
   - `Supplier<Double>`
4. `DecIntInt` → one of:

   - `IntBinaryOperator`
   - `BinaryOperator<Integer>`
   - `ToIntBiFunction<Integer, Integer>`
   - `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer>`